# How to focus textarea clicked main class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/eZNWWY)** you can see the comment textarea when you click the textarea then the `.CinP` background color will changing. I want also when clicked `.CinP` the `.Cj4Jbc` textarea will be focus.

How can i do that? Anyone can help me in this regard ?

**HTML :**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="CinP">
      <img src="http://www.technobuffalo.com/wp-content/
                uploads/2015/01/neytiri-avatar-5824.jpg"
           class="FhCbmb" width="36px" height="36px" />
      <div class="SO1PZd">
         <div class="ejZfNc">
            <textarea class="Cj4Jbc" id="InXt10" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
         </div>
         <div class="O0WRkf">SEND</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$(".CinP").focusin(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#fefefe");
});

$(".CinP").focusout(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#000000");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the requirement correctly then this should do the trick. [Working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGOmjp)

```
$(".CinP").click(function() {
     $(this).find('textarea.Cj4Jbc').focus();
});
```

Comment: thank you your answer is what i want. it works multiple.

Answer (score 0):

**[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpdWvO)**

You could focus an element using `focus()` :

```
$(".CinP").click(function() {
    $(".Cj4Jbc").focus();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the container is an example. I mean it need to work clicked just `.CinP`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the triggering event to be a `focusin`. Maybe your page navigation calls for this, instead of a simple click. In order to make the `div.CinP` itself focusable you should add to it a `tabindex` attribute.

How about

```
$(".CinP").focusin(function() {
   $(this).css("background-color", "#fefefe");
   $('.Cj4Jbc').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS solution:

```
.CinP:hover {
   background: #fefefe;
} 

.CinP:hover .Cj4Jbc {
   border: 1px solid blue;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
}
```